# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on iMac 21.5 using wireless keyboard!

Tags: installation, keyboard, mac

Good evening everyone. I am planning to dual boot Ubuntu and Mac OS on my iMac however I faced an issue. Mostly everyone seggest to use wired keyboard while installing Ubuntu on Mac however I don't have an opportunity and ability to borrow or buy new one, so is there any chance for me to install ubuntu using wireless Apple keyboard?
Thanks in advance

P.S. I have a wired mouse

P.S. I am able to connect my Apple keyboard in liveCD by clicking bluetooth icon and connecting it. However It doesn't work (keyboard) until that. (which means I cannot choose anything at CD start menu until connect it)

Comment: Do you understand why everyone has suggested using a wired keyboard while installing?

Comment: yes I do, because either wise you are not be able to use it, however I tried life CD and it actually worked after I clicked on bluetooth icon and click connect keyboard (I have wired mouse) however before that I couldn't do anything because the keyboard wasn't connected so that's why I asking if it's possible to make keyboard work when it will(for example) ask me in the end of installation to press enter? or I could just use reset button?

Comment: You should put that important info into your question (that you have a wired mouse and was able to use bluetooth through the LiveCD).  I don't know if the installation will work in a similar way, but probably someone else will know.

Comment: just get a wired keyboard and be done with it....

Comment: You might run into the possibility that Bluetooth might not be enabled and paired after you reboot after the install is finished. So then you might be stuck trying to borrow a keyboard and USB MOUSE just to pair up the wireless ones, then you can return them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The bluetooth daemon has not been started when you're running the installation, it starts when you enter the desktop environment. That's why you can use it with the Live CD but not in the installation process. You should get a wired keyboard (a cheap USB keyboard will do fine, perhaps some friend has one spare) and keep it around - if your computer crashes and you have to do something related to grub or using the terminal before the desktop environment has been started, you will need it.

I'm using an Apple Wireless keyboard myself, but I have a wired Apple keyboard in the drawer for this sort of occasion.

Comment: This was driving me up the wall....Not a mac, but I had wireless kbd and couldn't figure out why it was freezing up on me.  Thanks for the post.